# Restrict user from entering mulitple dots in numeric input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form, where the user can enter a price in one of the fields. The price should be entered as a floating number. I want to restrict the user from entering any other character different than a number or dot. So far I have been able to do this with some javascript code. But the problem is that I am able to enter multiple dots, which makes the price value invalid. Sure, the numeric input field treats this as an error and gives an error message, but I want dynamically to restrict entering second dot once the first one is entered. Below you can see my function, which I use at the moment.

I have tried the following. The function is called on every user key press. My idea was to get the value, entered so far in the numeric field and if a dot is already present, skip the user input. But it seems that the numeric input field does not return the current value using the val() function. It returns empty string. Even the text() and html() functions do not return the text, entered so far.

The function that I have so far:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    var text = $('#price_value').val();
    var isDecimalPresent = text.indexOf(".");
    if (charCode === 46 && isDecimalPresent > -1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode !== 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The input field:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" id="price_value" autocomplete="off" value="0.0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

I expect that when the user enters one dot, then tries to enter another dot, the key press to be ignored and the second dot to not be entered in the numeric field, leaving only a valid value.

Comment: Should probably be something like `if(charCode === 190 && (text.split('.').length - 1) > 1){ return false; }`.

Comment: On myside, the function works well. I am using `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @icecub: The problem is that the "text" value is empty. It appears that the string, returned by val() is empty if the value, entered in the text field is not valid, or something like that

Comment: @KingStone: I am using version v1.12.4 of jquery. Do you suggest, that the val() function works better or at least as I expect on version 1.8.3?

Comment: Yes, works `val`

Comment: @KingStone: On my side it didn't work. If I enter 1, it gets it correctly, if I enter . then it does not get any text. If I enter another 1, then the val() will return 1.1, but if I enter another dot -> 1.1. in this situation I am still getting empty string. Plus, I need a newer version of the jquery for the boostrap to work.

Comment: Ah yes, I had a similar issue not too long ago. The problem is the keypress event. This should be a keydown event instead. Otherwise it keeps on missing the last input.

Comment: @icecub: Even with keydown event I am still not able to achieve what I need. The problem is that I need to have the raw value of the input field. And in a number type input field if some invalid value is entered, it returns empty string as a value

Comment: Alright I've spend quite some time on getting you what you want, but the biggest issue here is the way input fields of type number work. The decimal actually doesn't become part of the field's value untill it's followed by a number. So `123.` actually returns the value of `123` untill you change it to `123.#`. Hence the decimal can't be detected if the user decides to type multiple decimals after eachother. The best I could come up with so far is this: [https://jsfiddle.net/vmyakwpd/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/vmyakwpd/3/). It works for the most part, just becomes an issue when a user types `#..`

Comment: Unfortunatelly it also considers this input: "1..11". I think I should go with text input instead of number input